# Automated daily metadata backups

Tags: metadata, eclipse

My sandbox was refreshed without my knowledge, causing me to lose my work.  Because of this, I want to try and automate backing up metadata.  I am thinking of using Eclipse Force.com IDE to do this, but not sure if it's possible.  Can you run Eclipse from the command line, telling it to open a project, refresh from the server, and then exit?  Other option would be to write a simple Java app which just dumps everything from an org, and use the Windows Task Scheduler to run it every night.

Comment: you could use a local git repository

Comment: how would I do that exactly?

Comment: look up a plugin for eclipse called egit

Comment: Eclipse also supports Subversion through [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA).

Comment: Also I believe you can use ANT scripts from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a process that could work for you.

1. Create a Ant build.xml which would download the required metadata. You can read more about this tool [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_deploying_ant.htm).
2. In the same directory where the ant build file is, create a local git repository. Read more about git [here](http://[http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics).

Below command will create a new git repository in the current directory

```
git init
```

Below command will add all files from current directory and its subdirectories

```
git add --all *
```

Below command will commit the files to repository

```
git commit -m "refreshing salesforce metadata"
```

3. [Optional] If you want to backup the data remotely, you can use either github.com [paid for private repositories] or bitbucket.com [free for private repositories]
4. Create a windows batch script (.bat) file or unix shell script (.sh) file and schedule it to run at appropriate interval.

This should set you up for automated backup.

Answer (score 2):

I have gotten this working (on Windows) as well for DIY automated SFDC backups:

lan-morey/force-meta-backup
https://github.com/alan-morey/force-meta-backup